# iTextSharp exception "Stack empty" when getting text from a PDF page

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, pdftotext

I am trying to loop through each page on a PDF to look for specific keywords. Code works fine on other PDFs, except this [one](http://disclosure.bursamalaysia.com/FileAccess/apbursaweb/download/?name=EA_DS_ATTACHMENTS&id=160045)

My code

```
Using oReader As New pdf.PdfReader(pdfFilename)

    For pCurrent = oReader.NumberOfPages To 1 Step -1
        Dim strategy As pdf.parser.ITextExtractionStrategy = New pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()
        Dim pageText As String = pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(oReader, pCurrent, strategy)

        '
        'search for keywords
        '
        'FindVOI

    Next 'proceed next page

End Using
```

Here is the snippet of code that causing this exception,

```
Dim pageText As String = pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(oReader, pCurrent, strategy)
```

Is showing exception `Stack empty` at page 98 on this [PDF](http://disclosure.bursamalaysia.com/FileAccess/apbursaweb/download/?name=EA_DS_ATTACHMENTS&id=160045), any ideas what is wrong?

Full Exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.dll
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>VipMonitorService.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Stack empty.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.EndMarkedContentC.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.ProcessContent[E](Int32 pageNumber, E renderListener, IDictionary`2 additionalContentOperators)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfReader reader, Int32 pageNumber, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy)
   at WatcherApp.VipMonitorService.PDFHelper.FindVOI(List`1 voiList, String pdfFilename, Boolean searchFromLast, Int32 searchNumberOfPagesInPercent) in \\Mac\Dropbox\git\Personal\WatcherApp\VipMonitorService\PDFHelper.vb:line 59
   at WatcherApp.VipMonitorService.Controller.ProcessAnnualReport(Announcement a) in \\Mac\Dropbox\git\Personal\WatcherApp\VipMonitorService\Controller.vb:line 456
   at WatcherApp.VipMonitorService.Controller.ProcessARInQueueThread() in \\Mac\Dropbox\git\Personal\WatcherApp\VipMonitorService\Controller.vb:line 362
   at WatcherApp.VipMonitorService.Controller._Lambda$__40-0() in \\Mac\Dropbox\git\Personal\WatcherApp\VipMonitorService\Controller.vb:line 339
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.EndMarkedContentC.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.ProcessContent[E](Int32 pageNumber, E renderListener, IDictionary`2 additionalContentOperators)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfReader reader, Int32 pageNumber, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy)
   at WatcherApp.VipMonitorService.PDFHelper.FindVOI(List`1 voiList, String pdfFilename, Boolean searchFromLast, Int32 searchNumberOfPagesInPercent) in \\Mac\Dropbox\git\Personal\WatcherApp\VipMonitorService\PDFHelper.vb:line 59
   at WatcherApp.VipMonitorService.Controller.ProcessAnnualReport(Announcement a) in \\Mac\Dropbox\git\Personal\WatcherApp\VipMonitorService\Controller.vb:line 456
   at WatcherApp.VipMonitorService.Controller.ProcessARInQueueThread() in \\Mac\Dropbox\git\Personal\WatcherApp\VipMonitorService\Controller.vb:line 362
   at WatcherApp.VipMonitorService.Controller._Lambda$__40-0() in \\Mac\Dropbox\git\Personal\WatcherApp\VipMonitorService\Controller.vb:line 339
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
```

Comment: The stack trace seems to indicate that you have an end-marked-content instruction without the matching begin-marked-content instruction. I'll later look into the PDF.

Answer (score 3):

> Is showing exception Stack empty at page 98 on this [PDF](http://disclosure.bursamalaysia.com/FileAccess/apbursaweb/download/?name=EA_DS_ATTACHMENTS&id=160045), any ideas what is wrong?

The stack trace shows that the *Stack empty* occurs at `iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.EndMarkedContentC.Invoke`. Thus, we should look at the starting and ending marked content operators:

> *tag*
>   **BMC**
>   Begin a marked-content sequence terminated by a balancing **EMC** operator. *tag* shall be a name object indicating the role or significance of the sequence.
>
> *tag properties*
>   **BDC**
>   Begin a marked-content sequence with an associated property list, terminated by a balancing **EMC** operator. *tag* shall be a name object indicating the role or significance of the sequence. *properties* shall be either an inline dictionary containing the property list or a name object associated with it in the **Properties** subdictionary of the current resource dictionary (see 14.6.2, “Property Lists”).
>
> *—*
>   **EMC**
>   End a marked-content sequence begun by a **BMC** or **BDC** operator.

*(Table 320 – Marked-content operators, ISO 32000-1)*

If you look at the **BDC**/**BMC** and **EMC** starts and ends of marked content on the page in question, you'll see:

```
/Artifact <</O /Layout >>BDC
EMC 
/Artifact <</O /Layout >>BDC  
EMC  
/Artifact <</O /Layout >>BDC  
EMC 
/Artifact <</BBox [0 33.8887 407.4289 0 ]/O /Layout >>BDC  
EMC 
EMC
...
```

Thus, there is a surplus **EMC** operator for which there is no **BMC** or **BDC** operator to end the marked content of.

Thus, this document is not a valid PDF; in particular, its marked content structure is broken.

---

That been said, it would be appropriate if iTextSharp would check the stack before the `Pop` and optionally either throw a more tangible exception or ignore the **EMC** operator.

Comment: I think I might be running into a similar problem. How did you view the marked content on that pdf?

Comment: I used a browser of the internal structure of PDFs, like [iText RUPS](https://itextpdf.com/products/rups) or [PDFBox PDFDebugger](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html#pdfdebugger). Adobe Acrobat Pro Preflight contains such a tool, too. Either of them can be used to inspect page content streams.